# How to implement a Weyl semimetal in tight binding?

Tags: python, tight-binding, electronic-transport, weyl-semimetal, topological-matter

I want to study electronic and thermal transport properties of a Weyl semimetal. Until now, I have used only the continuum model hamiltonian ($H=k⋅σ$). As the continuum model has several limitations, a lattice model would potentially be an improvement. But, more realistic studies could be done with tight binding analysis. However, as a beginner, I don't know how to implement a Weyl semimetal in a tight binding model.

I have seen several example of tight binding codes to implement Graphene and other 2D topological materials using [kwant](https://kwant-project.org/), but didn't find any example for a Weyl semimetal.

Is there any example codes written by others (ideally in Python)? Are there any dedicated Python packages (other than kwant) to handle it?

Comment: Hi SG_commun20! Did you find anything since January?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.